# Certain limit implies Cauchy sequence

Tags: calculus, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

I am reading a proof in which the following result is assumed.

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a real valued sequence such that
$$
\limsup_{m\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{m}\log|x_{m+1}-x_m| < 0.
$$
Then $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Could someone help me with proving this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a $c < 0$ such that for all large enough $m$ you have $\log \lvert x_{m+1} - x_m\rvert \leqslant mc$.

Comment: **Hint:-** Assume $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not Cauchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\limsup_{m\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{m}\log\lvert x_{m+1}-x_m| < 0$, then 
$$
\frac{1}{m}\log\lvert x_{m+1}-x_m| < -a,
\quad\text{whenever $m\ge n_0$},
$$
for some $a>0$ and for some $n_0\in\mathbb N$. Thus
$$
\lvert x_{m+1}-x_m|<\mathrm{e}^{-ma}, \quad\text{whenever $m\ge n_0$},
$$
and hence
$$
\lvert x_m-x_n|\le \lvert x_m-x_{m-1}|+\cdots+\lvert x_{n+1}-x_n|\le \sum_{k=n}^{m-1}\mathrm{e}^{-ka}\le \sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-ka}=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-na}}{1-\mathrm{e}^{-a}} 
$$
whenever $m\ge n\ge n_0$.